# Django get specific users profile

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a implemented a feature in my blog app that allows you to click on a user and view their profile / posts.

I want to display information from the users profile such as the bio and profile picture. I was able to successfully display the username but nothing else.

To solve this issue I need to get the specific users profile but I am unsure of the proper way to do this

Been playing around with a few methods but haven't had anything work and all of the solutions I have found online are about getting the current user

views.py

```
    class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_posts.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        userBio = User.objects.get('bio') #not working
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile,self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

HTML

```
<div class="content-section">
<div class="media">
    <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
    <div class="media-body">
        <h2 class="account-heading">{{ view.kwargs.username }}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

Should i be doing it like

```
    def get_user_profile(self):
    profile = request.get_profile(User)
    return profile
```

and then accesse it in the template with `get_user_profile`? Or should i still be working within the query set

Comment: Can you share the template where you are attempting to display the profile data?

Comment: added html to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go through the user's profile

```
user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
userBio = user.profile.bio
```

Comment: Thank you! how would I go about accessing it in the template?

Comment: @Wazy you can do the same in your template too `{{user.profile.bio}}` but you need to pass `user` instance from the context  in your template.

Comment: Sorry still learning and having some issues implementing this should I be doing it like I just posted in the update?